# Test user view with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, automated-tests

I'm pretty new to Rails, RSpec and Capybara and I'm trying to set up a automated test-suit, that tests how the user would interact with a webpage.

For this purpose I would like to know if there is a method to check if Capybara (using Selenium driver 2.43.0) 'sees' a certain area of a page. By 'sees' I mean if it would be visible to the user in this moment.

E.g. I have a button on my page that scrolls all the way to the bottom, so now I want to test if this buttons really serves its purpose.

I couldn't find any documentation on this issue. The only thing I found is how to make Capybara scroll to the bottom, but this is not what I want.

Comment: if button is available on page then it will find it automatically

Comment: @Mandeep I'm not wondering if Capybara can find a button on a page but I want to know what part of the page does Capybara see after clicking it. I want to make sure the button made the page scroll all the way down to the bottom e.g.

Comment: what exactly you want to test? Why can't you can check for focus event?

Comment: I want to test if the site was scrolled all the way to the bottom by clicking a button, which should make the page scroll to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can use Capybara's `click_link` or `click_button` methods:

```
click_link 'Save'
```

This will find a button on the page called 'Save' and click it. You can also pass `click_link` an element id, eg `'div#save'`.

```
click_button 'Save'
```

Alternatively you can use `click_button`.

This will test that the button is present and check that the button works.

Comment: but this doesn't tell me if the button was in the "user view" when I executed click_link. As I understand it, capybara will click this link even if it's not currently in visible part of the page (e.g. if you use save_and_open_screenshot)

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'not currently visible'. Capybara will still click the link if it is hidden by CSS or JavaScript but it can only click the link if it is a HTML element on the page. Capybara will not allow you to test JavaScript, for that you would need to use something like Selenium.

Comment: My definition of 'not currently visible' is, if I run the command save_and_open_screenshot, Capybara will show me what it sees at the moement. If a element is not on that screenshot I would say it is not currently visible, since I can't see it